# Basic question on Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, notation

Suppose $\Omega$ is a linear operator and,
$$\Omega|v_1\rangle = |w_1\rangle$$
$$\implies \langle v_2|\Omega|v_1\rangle = \langle v_2|w_1\rangle$$
$$\langle v_2|\Omega = \langle w_2|$$
$$\implies \langle v_2|\Omega|v_1\rangle = \langle w_2|v_1\rangle$$

How do I prove that,
$$\langle v_2|w_1\rangle == \langle w_2|v_1\rangle ?$$

That is, 
$$ \langle v_2|\Omega \space. |v_1\rangle == \langle v_2\space . |\Omega|v_1\rangle ?$$

Comment: how do you define the action of $\Omega$ on bras?

Comment: I guess $\Omega$ on any bra <A| produces a bra which is conjugate to the ket we would have got on applying $\Omega$ on |A>

Comment: for that definition to work, you would have to define $\Omega^\dagger$. How do you want to define the conjugate of $\Omega$?

Comment: I think, the statement is only true if $\Omega$ is hermitian.

Comment: I don't need to define $\Omega^{\cross}$ for that. I am applying conjugate only to the ket that has been produced after the operation.

Comment: Anyway, thank  you. You led me to the right track. I searched for "operation on bras" and found out that it is defined this way that both the things are equal.

Comment: Can I ask what the period / dot represents, in the last line? You don't really need it for operations within Dirac notion, or I should say, I have never seen it used.

Comment: Yes, it was part of my confusion. I was assuming that doing the operation on bra first and then applying ket will lead to a different result.

Comment: The dot is only meant to signify sequence of operations.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, sorry, my definition is wrong. You were right I gave the definition for adjoint of an operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the fun parts of Dirac notation. It distracts from subtleties like this.

So how do we prove your statement? Let's use a more standard mathematical notation, such that $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ is the inner product between two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Furthermore, let us define by $v^*$ the dual vector to $v$ (that is, if $v$ is represented by $|v\rangle$ then $v^*$ is represented by $\langle v|$), so that $v_1^*v_2=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$. Then the statement that $\langle w_2|\equiv\langle v_2|\Omega$ is the same as the statement that $w_2^*=v_2^*\Omega$. We thus need to define a sensible way for $\Omega$ to act on a dual (bra) vector. We define the adjoint $\Omega^{\dagger}$ of our linear operator by the statement that $w_2^*=(\Omega^{\dagger}v_2)^*$ (traditionally, $\Omega$ is defined as a map from the vector space to itself and $\Omega^{\dagger}$ is defined as a map from the dual space to itself, however we will ignore this for now).

From this definition, we can make the following translation from Dirac notation to the more mathematical notation:

$$\langle v_2|(\Omega|v_1\rangle)\to\langle v_2,\Omega v_1\rangle$$
$$(\langle v_2|\Omega)|v_2\rangle\to\langle\Omega^{\dagger}v_2,v_1\rangle$$

Now, a miracle occurs. Since our inner product is defined as multiplying dual vectors with vectors, the equality $\langle v_2,\Omega v_1\rangle=\langle\Omega^{\dagger}v_2,v_1\rangle$ is simply

$$(\Omega^{\dagger}v_2)^*v_1=v_2^*(\Omega v_1)$$

Which is **exactly** how we defined the operation of $\Omega$ on dual vectors (bras).

Now, we just need to make sure that our definition of $\Omega^{\dagger}$ fits in with our intuition of a conjugate transpose. This isn't too hard to see if you note that, for a finite dimensional complex vector space, the dual vectors are row vectors with the conjugate entries (this is just how we define the inner product in these Hilbert spaces). Under this definition, show that $\Omega^{\dagger}$ is indeed just $\overline{\Omega}^T$ (it shouldn't be too hard).

This is the fantastic thing about Dirac notation. It allows you to mix and match which operators are acting in which space, so long as their adjoints are well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.But $(\Omega^{\dagger}v_2)^*v_1=(v_2^*\Omega) v_1$, no? How do you justify, within the context of your construction, making the operator operate on the right first. Or am I missing something here.

Comment: The basic idea here is that the multiplication in these spaces is associative. Say, for instance, that $\Omega=vw^*$ is the outer product of two vectors $v$ and $w$. Then, since vector multiplcation is associative, we have $v_2^*(\Omega v_1)=v_2^*(vw^*v_1)=(v_2^*vw^*)v_1=(v_2^*\Omega)v_1$, as desired.